# Impact of containerization on choosing programming language

Tags: docker, containers

Does containerization affect a programming language being compiled/interpreted ?

Eg: Python is interpreted. C is compiled. When I dockerize my application, docker takes care of packing the dependents and building an image. So does choosing the programming language compiled/interpreted have an impact in this scenario ?

I read that interpreted languages are slow compared to compiled languages. Wanted to know in the dockerized world we are in, is it still relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether you run your workloads in docker container or on the host doesn't really impact performance in any way (broadly speaking)

Comment: Containerization doesn't impact to performance commonly. So your choice should be based on other criteria, such as your skills, your goals, technological stack in your team, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

When you containerize an interpreted application, the container also contains the interpreter. The application is executed in exactly the same way as it would be without the container.